# Sort and Save the list with sortorder

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

Hi i need to sort my list and save it basically i have list of reviews i want to give more priority for some and less for some as example  i'm using something like this.

```
<div class="group">
<div id="item1">
    this is item 1
</div>
<div id="item2">
    this is item 2
</div>
<div id="item3">
    this is item 3
</div>
<div id="item4">
    this is item 4
</div>
</div>
```

and i use JQueryUI sort function to drag and sort my list to custom order problem is what is the best way to save sorted order in back end.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

loop through sorted div you will get new sequence and save it

```
  var divlist = $(".group").children()
    var divseq= {}
$.each(divlist ,function(key ,val){

    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    divseq[key] = $(this).attr('id') 

})
console.log(divseq);
    $.get('your url',divseq) //send request to your page which will process sequece
```

// it will send parameter like 0,1,2,3  for position of div

Comment: thanks ddw147 my problem is how i do the saving part in sql. to update sortindexes

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe you will update in sql in one string like 3,2,4,1 or over  multple row or column

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you can use the nestable jquery plugin ( https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable )

download the plugin and see the below code

### index.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nestable.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nestable.css" type="text/css"/>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
$db         = mysql_select_db("testdb", $connection) or die("Could not select dataBase");
?>

<div id="nestable3" class="dd" style="width:300px">
<ol class="dd-list">
<?php 
$get = mysql_query("select * from sample order by sort");
while($set = mysql_fetch_object($get))
{
?>
<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="<?php echo $set->id; ?>">
    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div>
    <div class="dd3-content"><?php echo $set->heading; ?></div>    
</li>
<?php
}   
?>
</ol>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var updateOutput = function(e)
    {
        var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sort.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {myData:JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))},
        }).done(function( msg )
        {
            //display some message if you want
        });
    };
    $('#nestable3').nestable().on('change', updateOutput);
});
</script>
```

### sort.php

```
<?php 
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
$db         = mysql_select_db("testdb", $connection) or die("Could not select dataBase");

$stringJSON = $_REQUEST['myData'];  
$stringObject = json_decode(stripslashes($stringJSON),true);

recursor($stringObject, $db);
function recursor($complex_array, $db)
{
    foreach ($complex_array as $n => $v)
    {
        $id = $v['id'];
        $indx = $n+1;
        if($id)
        {
        $qry = mysql_query("update sample set sort = {$indx} where id = ".$id);
        }
        if (is_array($v))
            {
            recursor($v, $db);
            }
    }
}
?>
```

and dont forget to mark this if it was helpful